# MySQL select help; Subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables that I'm querying from. In one table, there are fields which denote if a player featured on a photo is dead/alive, in the Hall of Fame, etc. The field that I just added is called "new_flag". This denotes whether the photo is new to my inventory

Without a GROUP BY, the results would look something like this (Note some players have more than one product/photo)

```
name            firstname  lastname     hall_of_fame  deceased  new_flag
----            ---------  --------     ------------  --------  --------
EARL AVERILL SR EARL       AVERILL SR   Y             Y         Y
BILL TERRY      BILL       TERRY        Y             Y         N
BILL TERRY      BILL       TERRY        Y             Y         Y
BILL TERRY      BILL       TERRY        Y             Y         N
BOBBY DOERR     BOBBY      DOERR        Y             N         N
BOBBY DOERR     BOBBY      DOERR        Y             N         N
```

With a GROUP BY my query looks like this, but it cannot always find the new flag since each player may have more than one record.

```
SELECT    CONCAT(a.firstname,' ',a.lastname) AS name,
          a.firstname,
          a.lastname,
          b.hall_of_fame,
          b.deceased,
          b.new_flag
 FROM     vm_product_name AS a,
          vm_product_new_attribute AS b  
 WHERE    b.hall_of_fame ='Y'
   AND    a.product_id = b.product_id
 GROUP BY CONCAT(a.firstname,' ',a.lastname)
 ORDER BY a.lastname,
          a.firstname;
```

The problem is that I only only want each player to appear once on my webpage, but.....I also want to add a "new" icon next to the player's name if they have at least 1 new photo. Any ideas how I can do this?

I know this is not the optimal way to do this, but it is built as a Joomla/Virtumart extension and I cannot change the database structure at this time.

Comment: As an aside, you can group by multiple columns, so don't use the CONCAT in the group by clause, just use "GROUP BY a.firstname, a.lastname".  The main reason to avoid using functions in GROUP BY (as well as WHERE and ORDER BY) clauses is that it will prevent MySQL from using an index, and might cause it ti build a temporary table which will slow down your query significantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) AS name, a.firstname, a.lastname,
    b.hall_of_fame, b.deceased, MAX(b.new_flag) AS new_flag
FROM vm_product_name AS a
    INNER JOIN vm_product_new_attribute AS b
        ON a.product_id = b.product_id
WHERE b.hall_of_fame = 'Y'
GROUP BY a.lastname, a.firstname
ORDER BY a.lastname, a.firstname
```

Comment: +1: But, if for example there were two rows of a the same player and deceased had two different values it would pick one of the rows arbitrary. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: Thanks very much! I think this did it. @nate c Hmm. Is there anyway to keep this from happening?

Comment: Player's should have their own table without duplicates, but you said above you don't have control over the table.

Answer (score -1):

you may want a left join instead...

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT CONCAT(vm_product_name.firstname, ' ', vm_product_name.lastname) AS name
vm_product_name.firstname AS firstname, 
vm_product_name.lastname, AS lastname,
vm_product_new_attribute.hall_of_fame AS hall_of_fame,
vm_product_new_attribute.deceased AS deceased, 
vm_product_new_attribute.new_flag AS new_flag
FROM vm_product_name LEFT JOIN vm_product_new_attribute ON vm_product_name.product_id = vm_product_new_attribute.product_id 
ORDER BY lastname, firstname) AS MYRESULT GROUP BY CONCAT(lastname, ' ',firstname);
```

Comment: what does left join accomplish? There is no problems with nulls not joining.

Comment: Uhh HELLO! What if table B does not have a matching product_id? it would be excluded...  ** That is the entire user would be excluded...